# Getting the original sender when forwarding emails

Tags: mailgun

How can I get the address of the original sender, when an email has been forwarded to Mailgun?

The chain of events looks like this:

1. originalSender sends message to someUser
2. someUser forwards message to Mailgun
3. Mailgun POSTs a parsed message to my server

Put in another way:

```
orignalSender (send)->  someUser (forward)->  mailgun (POST)->  myserver
```

The best I could get is doing a regex on the "body-plain" property.
The problem is that email clients do send this differently. Here are two examples.

Forwarding from GMail (I added the ...):

```
body-plain: "---------- Forwarded message ----------\r\nFrom: Kalle Kalleson <kalle.kalleson@mail.com>\r\nDate: 2014-02-13\r\n ..."
```

Forwarding from Apple's Mail (I added the ...):

```
body-plain: "(...)Begin forwarded message:\r\n\r\n> From: Kalle Kalleson <kalle.kalleson@mail.com>\r\n> Subject: New color printer\r\n> Date: 11 February, 2014 15:47:19 GMT+1\r\n>
```

There must be a better way of doing this, right?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've just been in contact with Mailgun support and they could not offer a different strategy.
That is, parsing the body myself, taking in account the differences between email clients.
Lame I would say, :-(

Here you can vote up the feature request.
http://mailgun.uservoice.com/forums/156243-general/suggestions/5528656-extract-the-original-sender-of-a-forwarded-email

Has anyone come up with a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing what you are looking for, but when Mailgun POSTs to your server, you should be able to pull the From field from the POST data. I'm using a node.js app to parse my messages, however, in PHP it would look something like:

```
<?php
    $from = $_POST["From"];
    echo "This message is from: ".$from;
?>
```

I apologize if I'm missing what you're asking.

Comment: Using my example, the `from` field will give _someUser_, whereas what I want is _originalSender_. You are missing the forwarding step.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression should do the trick in either case.
Try:

```
/(From:.*>)/g
```

Comment: This fails for clients which (in mind-boggling stupidity) localize the From: header name in forwarded messages.  You'd have to match something like `/^(From|Lähettäjä|Från|Fra|Aa?n|De|...):/` (obviously incomplete; could not quicky google a reasonably comprehensive version of this regex).

Comment: Whatever regex dialect you are using, the `/g` flag makes no sense here.  You'd only ever want to find the first match.  Also the greedy `.*` should probably be changed to a non-greedy `[^>]*`.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to take original sender of an email throw any mail services.

So, we implemented regex and take the first occurence of the match from mail html body.

> **Regex.Match** only returns first match so used this with below regex.

```
From:\s(.*?)>
```

https://regex101.com/r/1pUpPU/1